# How do I use the BigQueryDate class in the BigQuery nodejs client library?

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with a column of type "DATE". When I query the table with the [nodejs client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery) as per below, the date elements in the data are objects of the BigQueryDate class. The [documentation for the BigQueryDate class](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQueryDate.html) provides no explanation on how the use the class. I would like to convert the date objects to either JavaScript date objects, or date strings, so I can use the date data in my application.

```
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const query = "SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`";
bigquery.query(query, function(err, rows) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(rows);
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the source code linked there? It has more context: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/index.js.html#line1324

Comment: @Max888 https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#.date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only parameter that the class has is value, which is the date as a string of the form yyyy-mm-dd.

```
const { BigQueryDate } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
const date = new BigQueryDate("2019-01-20");
date.value; // returns string "2019-01-20"
```

Comment: So the only way to get the date value is to loop through every row and convert? There's no way to tell the query to return JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation and found my answer as below:
I'm assuming that you've executed query and looping through the rows

```
// Import the Google Cloud client library
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
...
//connect to BigQuery and get the results
...
//loop through the rows and print it on console.
console.log('Rows:');
rows.forEach(
row => console.log(`${row.Col1}:${row.Col2}:${(row.DateCol3).value}:${row.col4}`)
);
```

*Note: Here DateCol3 is date column in BigQuery dataset.*

Hope this helps many others.